# noexcept operator and enable_if_t: do they work together?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, noexcept

Consider the following class:

```
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<T>::value>
    f() noexcept {}

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<not std::is_void<T>::value>
    g() noexcept {}
};
```

As expected, this compiles:

```
s.f<void>();
```

This one does not instead:

```
s.g<void>();
```

What puzzles me is that the following `main` compiles with GCC (6.2) and doesn't compile with clang (3.9):

```
int main() {
    static_assert(noexcept(&S::f<void>), "!");
    static_assert(noexcept(&S::g<void>), "!");
}
```

I would have said the second assert failed because of the invalid specialization. The two compilers disagree on that.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I guess GCC decided to take a shortcut once it figured out `g` is a member function template and so that `noexcept` can only be `true`.

Comment: @T.C. It may be, but in this case the specialization is invalid. Shouldn't it fail for `S::g<void>` (let me say) _cannot exist_ actually?

Comment: I didn't say GCC is right.

Comment: Regardless of whether gcc is allowed to not instantiate `g<void>` or not, you're not actually testing the `noexcept`-ness of the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[except.spec]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#13):

> The set of potential exceptions of an expression `e` is empty if `e` is a
>   core constant expression (5.20).

That is, GCC does not even resolve the *template-id*, because it knows from the get-go that the result is `true` (since `g<void>` is not a static data member template specialization whose type has an overloaded `operator&`). While being clever, the behavior is non-conforming, because any occurrence of a *template-id* entails the substitution of the arguments into the declaration of the function template.

Comment: But it's only an error if we instantiate `g`, and we don't instantiate `g` unless we need the definition, and this doesn't entail overload resolution, right?

Comment: @Barry "Instantiation" is concerned with the definition of the function template. Which is why a function template is not instantiated unless its definition is required. The signature is instantiated in many more scenarios. Otherwise something like `decltype(g<void>())` would not look at `g`'s return type, which would be really weird.

Comment: But that case would involve doing overload resolution, which triggers instantiation.

Comment: @Barry It triggers the instantiation of the declaration. The definition is not instantiated.

Comment: Note also that `decltype(&S::g<void>)` fails to compile, as well as `decltype(&S::g<void>)` and some others. That said, from the answer it's not clear if you suggest it's a bug of GCC or not.

Comment: @skypjack It is absolutely clear. I said "the behavior is very probably non-conforming".  And yeah, `decltype(&S::g<void>)` cannot use the same heuristic that `noexcept` does, so the declaration needs to be instantiated.

Comment: Not clear because of the _probably_. It doesn't mean that **it is a bug**, it means that _it may be_ a bug. That's all. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack Fine, I'll make that an absolute statement.